# Ruby on Rails - Reload Class Cache on Demand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Does Ruby on Rails 3 (3.0.7) offer a mechanism to reload the class cache on demand?  I am running some tests where I overwrite some methods in ApplicationController and in some of my models to stub out authentication.  For example, I call a method (I'm using Cucumber for testing) in some of my tags (`Before('@tag')`) that does this:

```
ApplicationController.send(:define_method, :current_user) do
  @current_user ||= User.where(:id => cookies[:user_id]).first
end
```

...where the actual current_user method in ApplicationController has a different behavior.

This works great until I need to run some tests in which I do not want to stub out those methods.  With `config.cache_classes = true` set in my test environment, ApplicationController is not reinitialized without my monkey patch, making the tests I don't want to stub out fail.  With `config.cache_classes = false`, my monkey patch is forgotten on the next request, causing all of the tests that I need to stub to fail.

Ideally, I would like to be able to erase the class cache in an `After('@tag')` method, if this is possible.  How can I accomplish that?  Or is there a better way of stubbing out certain methods in certain scenarios that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take inspiration from [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308970/why-does-code-need-to-be-reloaded-in-rails-3/5309126#5309126), and make good use of `ActionDispatch::Callbacks`.

Comment: Okay, I didn't use the Dispatcher callback, but what I did was create a method called reload which I call in `After('@tag') do` which loads the two files which contain the classes which I monkey patched.  For example, `load "#{Rails.root}/app/controllers/application_controller.rb"`.  Now when my non-stubbed tests run, they run without the monkey patches.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just beware of something: when you reload a class, changes and add-ons will be taken into account but not deletions.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the heads-up.  I don't think my test stubbing methods are going to change, so as it stands now, this does the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionDispatch::Reloader.cleanup!
ActionDispatch::Reloader.prepare!
```

I posted the rationale behind this over here: [Why does code need to be reloaded in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308970/why-does-code-need-to-be-reloaded-in-rails-3/15941616)

If its bad to cross post the same answer, kindly let me know how its preferred to post an answer thats relevant to two questions...I'm happy to oblige.

Answer (score 0):

As of newer Rails (> 4.0), I was able to reload class definitions, in console, for instance, with `reload!`.