# How do I hook into Rails *after* files are reloaded on each request in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on a [gem](https://github.com/bradrobertson/apartment) that sets properties on ActiveRecord models (such as `table_name`) dynamically based on a user config option.

I have an initializer that achieves this.  My problem however is that in dev mode, these classes are reloaded, so they don't maintain these values set.

So I thought I'd use a railtie to hook into the point where these files are reloaded and run my config again on the models.  My problem however is that `config.to_prepare` in the railtie appears to run before the `reload!` actually takes place.  I can prove this with a bit of logging:

```
module MyMod
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie

    config.to_prepare do
      Rails.logger.debug("Contact object_id: #{Contact.object_id}")
    end
  end
end
```

if I load up my console, I get the first log:

```
Contact object_id: 2202692040
```

If I check `Contact.object_id` it matches up:

```
Contact.object_id  #=> 2202692040
```

Then I `reload!`

```
reload!
```

Rails logger from my `to_prepare` logs:

```
Contact object_id: 2202692040
```

So it still has the old object_id, but when I check it in the console:

```
Contact.object_id  #=> 2197355080
```

Which is the newly loaded class object id.

So how do I get `to_prepare` to run *after* the files are reloaded?  Using `Rails 3.0.10`

#### update

I've also tried manually attaching this action to the `after_prepare` callback on the `ActionDispatch::Callbacks` like so:

```
initializer "apartment.init" do
  ActionDispatch::Callbacks.set_callback(:prepare, :after) do
    Rails.logger.debug("Contact object_id: #{Contact.object_id}")
  end
end
```

It does indeed run the callback after the `config.to_prepare` but it still appears to happen `before` the files are reloaded...  I get the same behaviour as above.

Comment: have you tried something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308970/why-does-code-need-to-be-reloaded-in-rails-3/5309126#5309126

Answer (score 18):

Write an initializer that, if `cache_classes` is `false`, uses [`ActionDispatch::Reloader`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Reloader.html) to set a `to_prepare` callback that runs your gem's installation routine.

```
initializer 'foobar.install' do
  if Rails.configuration.cache_classes
    FooBar.install!
  else
    ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
      FooBar.install!
    end
  end
end
```

It'll work both in the console with the `reload!` method and in the Rack application server.

Comment: It seems that `to_prepare` [is called once](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.9/ActionDispatch/Callbacks/to_prepare/class) when classes are cached too, so you can just do: 
{
    ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
      FooBar.install!
    end
}

Comment: initializer did not work for me, but I removed that and it worked, is hard to find things as this in docs, thanks

Comment: For new Rails versions 5.x, we need to use `ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare` instead of `ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare`

Comment: For new Rails versions 6.x, we now have to use `Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare` instead of `ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Rails reloader only unhooks the constants. The models are reloaded with autoloading when the constants are referenced in your app.

In your callback, I think you have to trigger the load manually by referencing all the models. Maybe your gem can keep a list of all the models that include it, then just simply reference the constants to autoload them...

```
model_names.each { |model_name| model_name.constantize }
```

You can build the list with [`self.included`](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/):

```
module MyGem
  self.included(base)
    @model_names ||= Set.new
    @model_names += base.to_s
  end
end
```