# Rake task works in development, but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I've got a rake task that changes data on the homepage every few hours.  I've tested it out and it works fine in development.  But it doesn't work in production.  What do I have to do to get the changes I want to see?  Should I add a command that restarts the server?  Would that make the server acknowledge the change?  Is there a smarter way to do this?

The rake task is below.  It'll be run by heroku's scheduler add on, so it's currently in the lib/tasks/scheduler.rake file.

```
desc 'changes the meta tags'
task :mixup_meta_tags => :environment do 
  regex = /@meta_tag/
  file = File.open('app/controllers/site_controller.rb', 'r')
  lines = []
  file.each_line do |line|
    (line =~ regex) ? (lines << replace_line(line)) : (lines << line)
  end
  file.close
  file = File.open('app/controllers/site_controller.rb', 'w')
  lines.each{|line| file.write line} 
  file.close
end

def replace_line(line)
  meta_tags = MetaTag.all.map { |tag| tag["tag"] }
  new_tag = meta_tags.sample(1)[0]
  line = "    @meta_tag = \"#{new_tag}\" \n" # added the newline
end
```

Comment: Be more precise... start by posting your rake task code and how you run it. You should never restart your server to run a task.

Comment: No problem.  Just added rake task to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, changes to your Rails application in Production require a restart for them to get picked up by the server.  To get this to work on the fly you might want to try the solution mentioned in this post [why-does-code-need-to-be-reloaded-in-rails-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308970/why-does-code-need-to-be-reloaded-in-rails-3/5309126#5309126)

Comment: As I understand it, having `:environment` allows the task to run in any environment, whereas if I had `:production`, it'd be limited to the production environment.

Comment: :environment loads the current Rails environment for the task.  So `rake mix_up_meta_tags RAILS_ENV=production` would load the production environment, `rake mix_up_meta_tags` would load development since it's the default.

Comment: To clarify, I meant that in development changes to controllers get applied immediately, so when you run your task and it changes your site_controller, you don't have to restart the server.  However, in production you would need to restart the server to pickup the changes to your site_controller.