# Rake Task to Restart Heroku Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

I'm trying to create a rake task that restarts my heroku servier.  I've found this post, which has helped immensely: http://railspikes.com/2010/2/13/rake-task-for-deploying-to-heroku.

I've cobbled together this rake task, but it's giving me an error.  The rake abouts and I get the message:
    uninitialized constant Heroku::Command::BaseWithApp.

This is my method.

```
desc 'restarts the server'
task restart_server: :environment do
  require 'heroku'
  require 'heroku/command'
  user, pass = File.read(File.expand_path("~/.heroku/credentials.txt")).split("\n")
  heroku = Heroku::Client.new(user, pass)

  cmd = Heroku::Command::BaseWithApp.new([])
  remotes = cmd.git_remotes(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../..")

  remote, app = remotes.detect {|key, value| value == (ENV['APP'])}# || cmd.app)}

  if remote.nil?
    raise "Could not find a git remote for the '#{ENV['APP']}' app"
  end

  heroku.restart(ENV['APP'])
end
```

I'm not sure why it's rejecting Heroku::Command.  The app is already live on Heroku, so I know it's Heroku compliant.

Any advice?

EDIT: Here's my stack trace.

```
** Invoke restart_server (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute restart_server
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Heroku::Command::BaseWithApp
/Users/bendowney/Sites/ProblemChildApp/lib/tasks/scheduler.rake:51:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@ProblemChildApp/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/bendowney/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@ProblemChildApp/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => restart_server
```

Comment: it's not rejecting the command, you are using an unknown class ```Heroku::Command::BaseWithApp``` paste your stack-trace that you get while running your taks with ```--trace```

Comment: Can you clarify why executing the `heroku ps:restart` command directly won't suffice?

Comment: Due to apathy.  I've got a rake task that resets the webpages data and as I understand it, the only way to do this successfully is to restarting the server.  Here's a related post explaining my situation.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11668208/rake-task-works-in-development-but-not-in-production/11671573#11671573